# 10000000 cell limit error when appending a row with only 17 cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm getting an error when running my appscript suggesting that "this action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 10000000 cells.", even though I'm appending a row with only 17 cells.

This code used to run perfectly until I edited some lines that might have caused the error. By now I have pasted back my original code from a backup, but the error still occurs! The script imports documents from a Firebase database, adds each of the fields to an array and then appends the array as a row to the sheet. There are definitely not 10000000 documents in the database which should still not cause the error as the rows are appended one by one.

The error is caused when appending the first row.

This is the code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    const firestore=getFirestore();
    const spreadsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet=spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

    var range = sheet.getRange('A3:Z10000000');
    range.clear();

    const allDocuments=firestore.getDocuments('VormData');

    for(var i=0;i<allDocuments.length;i++){
     
      //Initialize the array to be printed to google sheets

      var docArray=[];

      var area=allDocuments[i].fields['Area'];
      if (roete != null){
        docArray.push(area.stringValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }

      var roete=allDocuments[i].fields['Roete'];
      if (roete != null){
        docArray.push(roete.stringValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }

      var staanplekNr=allDocuments[i].fields['StaanplekNr'];
      if (staanplekNr != null){
        docArray.push(staanplekNr.stringValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }

      var datumTyd=allDocuments[i].fields['DatumTyd'];
      if (datumTyd != null){
        docArray.push(datumTyd.timestampValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }

      var werknemerId=allDocuments[i].fields['WerknemerID'];
      if (werknemerId != null){
        docArray.push(werknemerId.stringValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }

      var getalStands=allDocuments[i].fields['GetalStands'];
      if (getalStands != null){
        docArray.push(getalStands.integerValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }
  
      var getalKorwe=allDocuments[i].fields['GetalKorwe'];
      if (getalKorwe != null){
        docArray.push(getalKorwe.integerValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }

      var geenSuperKorwe=allDocuments[i].fields['GeenSuperKorwe'];
      if (geenSuperKorwe != null){
        docArray.push(geenSuperKorwe.integerValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }

      var eenSuperKorwe=allDocuments[i].fields['EenSuperKorwe'];
      if (eenSuperKorwe != null){
        docArray.push(eenSuperKorwe.integerValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }

      var tweeSuperKorwe=allDocuments[i].fields['TweeSuperKorwe'];
      if (tweeSuperKorwe != null){
        docArray.push(tweeSuperKorwe.integerValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }

      var drieSuperKorwe=allDocuments[i].fields['DrieSuperKorwe'];
      if (drieSuperKorwe != null){
        docArray.push(drieSuperKorwe.integerValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }

      var vierSuperKorwe=allDocuments[i].fields['VierSuperKorwe'];
      if (vierSuperKorwe != null){
        docArray.push(vierSuperKorwe.integerValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }

      var supersTotaal=allDocuments[i].fields['SupersTotaal'];
      if (supersTotaal != null){
        docArray.push(supersTotaal.integerValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }

      var vangkaste=allDocuments[i].fields['Vangkaste'];
      if (vangkaste != null){
        docArray.push(vangkaste.integerValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }

      var supersGetrek=allDocuments[i].fields['SupersGetrek'];
      if (supersGetrek != null){
        docArray.push(supersGetrek.integerValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }

      var korweVrek=allDocuments[i].fields['KorweVrek'];
      if (korweVrek != null){
        docArray.push(korweVrek.integerValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }

      var opmerkings=allDocuments[i].fields['Opmerkings'];
      if (opmerkings != null){
        docArray.push(opmerkings.stringValue);
      }
      else {
        docArray.push("GEEN DATA");
      }
  
    //write array as row in google sheets
    sheet.appendRow(docArray); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```js
var range = sheet.getRange('A3:Z10000000');
```

It involves clearing 260 million cells or so. You need to reduce it to below 10 million in total.

To make it dynamic and more efficient, you can use this code that would take the last row to generate the range (with minimum set to 3 to avoid empty sheet errors):

```js
var range = sheet.getRange(`A3:Z${Math.max(sheet.getLastRow(), 3)}`)
range.clear();
```

Comment: I apologize for the fault in the code, I changed this range from 'A3:Z100000' right before posting the question as a desperate experiment to clear enough cells before running the rest of the code. I still appreciate the improved code and will rather use this to clear the cells. Now that this fault is solved I'm still getting the same error and it is again referring to this line as the problem: "sheet.appendRow(docArray); "

Comment: @Duits Can you share a sample document, please?  It will greatly simplify the debuging.

Comment: I was finally able to fix the problem by restoring an old version of the document (which does not restore the App Script) and then pasting my old code back into the App Script Project. So I still don't know what was causing the error, but it is no longer occurring.